# How to read in string input from the user and allocate it?

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, input

So I've been working on this code for a while now and I can't figure out why it's not working. Basically I'm suppose to create a program using functions to read in string input from the user which is the filename for “data.txt”. I need a function to determine the number of rows that are in the file in order to allocate an array of character pointers. Then my program should print out the strings read from the file. Finally the program should free the allocated memory.

This is my non-working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_WIDTH 144

void getFileName(char* array1);
int getLineCount(FILE* data, int max);
char** createArryOfPtrs(int rows);
int main(void) 
{
  int max = 0;
  int rows;
  char array1[MAX_WIDTH];
  FILE* data = fopen(array1, "r");
  getFileName(array1);
  getLineCount(data, max);
  createArryOfPtrs(rows);


  fclose(data);
  return 0;
}

void getFileName(char* array1)
{
  printf("Enter filename: ");
  fscanf(stdin, "%144[^\t]", array1);

}

int getLineCount(FILE* data, int max)
{
  int i = 4;
  char *array1[MAX_WIDTH];
  if(data != NULL)
  {
    while(fgets(*array1, MAX_WIDTH, data) != NULL)
    {
      i+=1;
    }
  }


return i;
}

char** createArryOfPtrs(int rows)
{
  int r = 4, c = 9, i, j, count;
  char *array1[r];
  for(i =0; i < r; i++)
  {
    array1[i] = (char*)malloc(c * sizeof(char));
  }
  count = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
      array1[i][j] = ++count;
    }
  }

  for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
    {
      printf("%c", array1[i][j]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This is the text file.

```
larry snedden 123 mocking bird lane
sponge bob 321 bikini bottom beach
mary fleece 978 pasture road
hairy whodunit 456 get out of here now lane
```

I'm still new to C so I'm very confused. Appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Type casting for `malloc` is unneeded.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too but my teacher says I need to allocate the array and I have no idea how to do that. Would I use calloc?

Comment: Memory allocation is a huge topic to study. When your teacher says you need to allocate memory for an array, you can allocate it statically or dynamically. Calloc (and malloc) will let you allocate memory dynamically. My comment was towards the typecast. Malloc returns a void pointer, so the typecast is unneeded, and harmless.

Answer (score 2):

Order matters! You get the name of the file to open *after* you call `fopen`. That means the data in `array1` will be uninitialized and *indeterminate* (and seem random).

You need to read the name of the file *first*.

This issue should have been very clear if you did a little [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks. Once I switch that around, would you say my code is good or is there more things I need to fix?

Comment: @Angie There are quite a few more things that needs to be fixed, most (if not all?) related to pointers and their use. For example in the `getLineCount` function, the expression `*array1` is equal to `array1[0]`, which results in an *uninitialized pointer*. And of course it's kind of confusing how you reuse the same name for all your arrays, even though they are different and for different purposes.